# php in_array not giving expected result

Tags: php

I have a stoopid noob question, but i just can't seem to find the answer.

i have the following data:

An array ($haystack):

```
 Array ( [0] => Field number 1__text__Fieldnumber1 [1] => Field number 2__text__Fieldnumber2 )
```

- String to search for in array (`$needle`): `Fieldnumber1`

I'm using a simple in_array search with the above

```
if (in_array($needle, $haystack) == true)
{
    echo "found";
}
else 
{
    echo "not found";
}
```

But the result is "not found"..... What am i not seeing?

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the array element and then use `in_array()` function.

Comment: `in_array()` searches for whole string, not part of it. You'll find `$needle` if you give `'Field number 1__text__Fieldnumber1'` as value.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer i was looking for ! (together with the answer of Rajdeep)

Comment: one wy? use `foreach` for each record. And check with `strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `in_array()` will try to match `$needle` with the whole string, not parts of the string. Hence first use `explode()` function to split the array element and then use `in_array()` function, like this:

```
$haystack = array ( 0 => "Field number 1__text__Fieldnumber1", 1 => "Field number 2__text__Fieldnumber2" );
$needle = "Fieldnumber1";

$flag = false;
foreach($haystack as $str){
    $array = explode("__", $str);
    if(in_array($needle, $array)){
        $flag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($flag){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```